# Draw lines a touches event not work perfectly on FullScreen mode in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am create app to draw on iphone Sucessfully.But,it's work only set Status bar is initially hidden = No in myapp-info.plist.else if,set Status bar is initially hidden=yes don't working Perfectly.My viewcontroller code is Below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    drawImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
    mouseMoved = 0;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    //lastPoint.y -= 20;

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 // [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20; // only for 'kCGLineCapRound'
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    //Albert Renshaw - Apps4Life
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0); // for size
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); //values for R, G, B, and Alpha
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }
    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        //if color == green
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setDrawImage:nil];
    [self setMy_view:nil];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [my_view release];
    [drawImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

This Code working perfectly on without fullScreen mode.else,does not working like Below output:

[image]

Please any one help me with us any code or examples...!

Thanks..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;` from 
 `- (void)viewDidLoad` method 
 to 
 `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` 
 Any geometry adjustments should be made in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

finally i am got it solution Below My Controller Class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    drawImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    drawImage.center=self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
    mouseMoved = 0;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 0;

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    //currentPoint.y += 20; // only for 'kCGLineCapRound'
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    //Albert Renshaw - Apps4Life
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0); // for size
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); //values for R, G, B, and Alpha
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }
    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        //if color == green
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)]; //originally self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound); //kCGLineCapSquare, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineCapRound
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setDrawImage:nil];
    [self setMy_view:nil];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [my_view release];
    [drawImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: You can leave initializations at viewDidLoad method as it's the best place to do those custom initializations. viewWillAppear method is your last chance for lightweight adjustments and in the scope of this method all geometry of the view hierarchy is properly set, so use it for fast operations (like setting the frame, center or some other minor stuff)

Comment: I don't know if it matters for speed (I'd be curious to find out) but for code clarity, you might want to store the context in a local variable rather than calling for it each time (e.g. `CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`)