# On iOS, why doesn't the drawing occur in the following code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to draw a rectangle where the user moves the finger on an iPad:

Interface of ViewController:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *paths;
}
```

Implementation:

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

        CGRect aRectangle = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 40, 40);
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:aRectangle];

        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:aRectangle];

        [paths addObject:path];       
    }
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    for (UIBezierPath *path in paths) {
        [path fill];
    }
}
```

but nothing will draw on screen... I thought maybe I didn't tell the view to refresh itself and call `drawRect`, but I tried going to iPad's home screen and re-enter the app and still nothing show?

(I was going to use an array of points, but since `CGPoint` is not an object that will stay, so it can't be added to the mutable array and also it will go away after the local scope ends.  How can it be an array of points instead?)

Comment: try below post for drawing...!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226130/draw-lines-a-touches-event-not-work-perfectly-on-fullscreen-mode-in-iphone

Thanks..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drawRect` is a method from `UIView` but not `UIViewController`. You gonna need to create your custom `UIView` subclass and overwrite `drawRect` in it, and then bind the custom view class to your view in XIB/NIB if you are using Interface Builder to build your UI structure.

Refer to [iPhone: why isn't drawRect getting called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053761/1241690)

Comment: how does the mutable array get passed to the UIView object?

Comment: You can add `@property (retain) NSMutableArray *path` to your custom UIView subclass, and access it in `ViewController` class by `self.view.path`.

Comment: I did choose `ViewController.xib` and chose the Custom Class to be TestView... but in `ViewController.m`, if I do  `self.view.paths`, it will say "Property 'paths' not found on object of type UIView"

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake. You gonna need to cast `self.view` to your custom class type and then access `paths`, or you will get warning at compile time. Sorry.

Comment: `paths` was null all the time... I added `testView.paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];` in `viewDidLoad` and I already see it getting bigger and bigger when there are Move events, but nothing is drawn

Comment: I don't have your code so I am not sure... But at least you should alloc `paths` in init method of your UIView but not in your view controller. Then try to debug and set a breakpoint in `drawRect` to see whether `paths` have objects added in it?

Comment: I think I got it, I just need to call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` after adding the path to the mutable array

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should implement these methods in a `UIView` instead of a `UIViewController`.

---

Secondly, never call drawRect yourself!

> I thought maybe I didn't tell the view to refresh itself and call
>   drawRect

If you want your view to redraw the next drawing cycle/frame, call -setNeedsDisplay on it.

Comment: yeah, I mean invalidate the view like on Win32 so that `drawRect` will be called

Comment: Call `-setNeedsDisplay` on it, this will force it to redraw.